# Properly update gravity of TextView programmatically?

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

I have a `TextView` contained in a `HorizontalScrollView`, and I want the text to be centered whenever not scrollable, but when it is big enough to be scrollable I need to change the gravity of the `TextView` to be `Gravity.LEFT`, otherwise the `HorizontalScrollView` will show the text wrong, as in it will cut off most of the text, and there will be empty space at the end if the text remains centered. Here is my current code to handle this:

```
//make horizontal scroll text center and work
final HorizontalScrollView toTextScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.horizScroll);

toTextScrollView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top,
                        int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop,
                        int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        //if scrollable, change toNumber layout_gravity to left, else keep it at center
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        if(canScroll(toTextScrollView))
            params.gravity=Gravity.LEFT;
        else
            params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;


        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Can scroll: " + canScroll(toTextScrollView), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        toNumber.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

});
```

My function `canScroll()` works properly as it updates in the Toast correctly, so that is not the issue. The issue is that I feel the `TextView` needs to "refresh" once the layout is set. This is because when the first number is added to the `TextView` that makes it scrollable, the Toast returns it is now scrollable but the Gravity remains centered and therefore the first part of the number is cut of when scrolling left, like this:

[image]

*However*, whenever the next number is added, it updates properly, the gravity is set to Gravity.LEFT, and therefore none of the text is cut off in the scroll view. How do I properly update the TextView gravity so it happens instantly?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling **view.invalidate** after you change the textview's gravity.

Comment: I tried both toNumber.invalidate() and toTextScrollView.invalidate(), neither worked.

Comment: @AggieDev Ok. I am sorry my answer didn't help